# The 'for each' logic on the child node is skipping parent nodes without children

Tags: xml, node.js, xslt

I am new to xslt and the only way to get all chidren nodes to show up is the do a for each at the beginning of the xslt.  However now parents without children are missing.  Please note the xml should be a flat csv and is working fine except for skipping parents where "" node is absent.

```
xlst:
 <wd:Report_Data xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/Report">
<wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Employee_ID>100099999</wd:Employee_ID>
    <wd:ADDRESS>Any Street</wd:ADDRESS>
    <wd:CITY>Any City</wd:CITY>
    <wd:PTIN>45-9999999</wd:PTIN>
    <wd:Part_3_-_Employer_provided_self-insured_coverage>1</wd:Part_3_-_Employer_provided_self-insured_coverage>
    <wd:Part_3_-_Covered_Individuals>
        <wd:NAME>Jane</wd:NAME>
        <wd:NAME2>Doe</wd:NAME2>
        <wd:TIN>999999998</wd:TIN>
    </wd:Part_3_-_Covered_Individuals>
    <wd:Part_3_-_Covered_Individuals>
        <wd:Covered_Individual_Name>Jaelyn Polanco</wd:Covered_Individual_Name>
        <wd:NAME>Jean</wd:NAME>
        <wd:NAME2>Doe</wd:NAME2>
        <wd:TIN>999999999</wd:TIN>
    </wd:Part_3_-_Covered_Individuals>
</wd:Report_Entry>
<wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Employee_ID>100099998</wd:Employee_ID>
    <wd:ADDRESS>Any Street</wd:ADDRESS>
    <wd:CITY>Any City</wd:CITY>
    <wd:PTIN>45-9999999</wd:PTIN>
    <wd:Part_3_-_Employer_provided_self-insured_coverage>0</wd:Part_3_-_Employer_provided_self-insured_coverage>
</wd:Report_Entry>
</wd:Report_Data>
```

XSLT:

```
 <xsl:for-each select="wd:Report_Data/wd:Report_Entry/wd:Part_3_-_Covered_Individuals">

                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="../wd:Part_3_-_Employer_provided_self-insured_coverage !=1 "  > 
                        <xsl:value-of select="$quote" /><xsl:value-of select="../wd:PTIN"/><xsl:value-of select="$quote" /><xsl:value-of select="$delimiter" />
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise> 
                        <xsl:value-of select="$quote" /><xsl:value-of select="../wd:PTIN"/><xsl:value-of select="$quote" /><xsl:value-of select="$delimiter" />
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>   

    <!-- <xsl:value-of select="$quote" /><xsl:value-of select="../wd:PTIN"/><xsl:value-of select="$quote" /><xsl:value-of select="$delimiter" />-->

                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="../wd:EE_SSN=wd:TIN"  > 
                        <xsl:value-of select="$quote" />    <xsl:text>S</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$quote" /><xsl:value-of select="$delimiter" />
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise> 
                            <xsl:value-of select="$quote" /><xsl:text>D</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$quote" /><xsl:value-of select="$delimiter" />
              </xsl:otherwise>
```

Comment: Please clean up your question and also include the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite incomprehensible, except for this part:

> the only way to get all chidren nodes to show up is the do a for each
>   at the beginning of the xslt. However now parents without children are
>   missing.

That's simply not true. Consider the following input:

**XML**

```
<root>
   <parent>
        <parent-id>101</parent-id>
        <child>
            <child-id>101-A</child-id>
        </child>
        <child>
            <child-id>101-B</child-id>
        </child>
   </parent>
   <parent>
        <parent-id>102</parent-id>
   </parent>
   <parent>
        <parent-id>103</parent-id>
        <child>
            <child-id>103-A</child-id>
        </child>
   </parent>
</root>
```

Applying the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="parent[not(child)]">
    <xsl:value-of select="parent-id"/>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="child">
    <xsl:value-of select="../parent-id"/>
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="child-id"/>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

will result in:

```
101,101-A
101,101-B
102
103,103-A
```

i.e. a row for each child as well as each childless parent.